# [excel 2013]How can I create a pie chart based on some distinct text values

Tags: excel-2013

I have some a file containing customer information (columns: country, customerID)  and I want to create a pie chart over countries.

Say I have 100 customer rows from several different countries/regions, like 13 customers in US, 10 from France, 7 from China, etc.

I'd like the pie chart to group the customers that from the same country together and then display where are those customers from in relation to each other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Select your data including labels and INSERT a PivotChart:

[image: SO28707874 example]

I sorted the customer count and added data labels in the chart after clicking inside the offered bar chart and then right-clicking Select Series Chart Type... to select Pie.